# how to get time difference in microseconds to measure total query-time in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to get process time of a query in microseconds.

I get always 0 result when i calculate the difference of two time(at the beginning and end of query) with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function.

Comment: Are you aware of `EXPLAIN` ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: i will log the process time of queries by time

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, you will only get millisecond accuracy.

Comment: @Craig Ringer yes i am ...thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [section 9.9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) of the documentation. The issue is (probably, given that you provide few details) that `current_timestamp` returns the time at the start of the transaction.

If you use `clock_timestamp`, you'll get different values within the transaction.

(If you want to time a lot of queries, you might be better off adjusting the logging of the server, if you have permission to do so. But for a one-off, this is probably ok.)

Comment: Or you could use psql's `\timing` function, or `explain analyze`, or `log_min_duration_statement`, ...